# How to Encode URL Contains Unicode Characters with PHP

Tags: php, urlencode

Currently, I'm trying to look for a solution to encode url which contains unicode characters, Khmer Unicode. I've tried using php built-in function urlencode() and it gives result: 
For example: http://www.example.com/?kwd=Mac+Book+Pro+នៅប្រទេសយើង

While I've tested with Google search, it results:
https://www.google.com.kh/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=Mac+Book+Pro+%E1%9E%93%E1%9F%85%E1%9E%94%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%91%E1%9F%81%E1%9E%9F%E1%9E%99%E1%9E%BE%E1%9E%84&oq=Mac+Book+Pro+%E1%9E%93%E1%9F%85%E1%9E%94%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%91%E1%9F%81%E1%9E%9F%E1%9E%99%E1%9E%BE%E1%9E%84

How to do that? Hope someone here would help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Recently, I had the same problem. In my case url was like this `https://www.tiktok.com/music/оригинальный-звук-6741058042634210054`. `urlencode` and  `rawurlencode` did not help me. And I found  `voku/portable-utf8` from github and it solved all my. Here is the link https://github.com/voku/portable-utf8

Answer (score 14):

For UTF-8 you can use:

```
urlencode(utf8_encode($string)); //for encoding

utf8_decode(urldecode($string)); //for decoding
```

For UTF-16 you can use this function (from notes for `urlencode` in http://php.net/urlencode):

```
function utf16_urlencode ( $str ) {
     # convert characters > 255 into HTML entities
     $convmap = array( 0xFF, 0x2FFFF, 0, 0xFFFF );
     $str = mb_encode_numericentity( $str, $convmap, "UTF-8");

     # escape HTML entities, so they are not urlencoded
     $str = preg_replace( '/&#([0-9a-fA-F]{2,5});/i', 'mark\\1mark', $str );
     $str = urlencode($str);

     # now convert escaped entities into unicode url syntax
     $str = preg_replace( '/mark([0-9a-fA-F]{2,5})mark/i', '%u\\1', $str );
     return $str;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, actually, I've already tried the above codes: urlencode(utf8_encode($string)); //for encoding but it still doesn't produce the same result as google does as stated in my question. I've even tried out the function: utf16_urlencode() but it doesn't product what i want. Thanks agian

Answer (score 2):

```
function cleanUrl($url) {
    $res= urlencode(utf8_encode($url));
    $res = str_replace("%3A",":",$res);
    $res = str_replace("%2F","/",$res);
    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rawurlencode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: Produced exactly what I needed, thank you.  This mirrors JavaScript's encodeURIComponent(), by the way.